# ExoPlayer manually setting HLS stream quality

Tags: exoplayer

Is there a way to manually change the quality of the video in an HLS stream during playback using ExoPlayer?  I want to be able to tweak the setting so that the user can switch between high, low and adaptive quality.

Answer (score 0):

According to an introductory video by Google Developers (), and ExoPlayer's own documentation, you can specify a FormatEvaluator when instantiating your DashChunkSource.

I'd recommend defining your own subclass of FormatEvaluator, and add a property to allow the user (through your UI) to specify the quality.

Comment: can you help me to redefine FormatEvaluator and how to add property?